# Batch file check office architecture version

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ms-office, spring-batch-admin

I have the following script, that will print the current version of office and the architecture of the OS

```vb
Echo off&SetLocal
Set "KEY="&Set "GUID="&Set "IOV="&Set "MWB=32"&Set "MOB=32"
Echo=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%|Find "64">Nul&&(
   Set "KEY=\Wow6432Node"&Set "MWB=64")
Set "KEY=HKLM\Software%KEY%\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
For /f "Delims=" %%a In ('Reg Query %KEY% /k /f "*-001B-*0FF1CE}"') Do (
   If Not Defined GUID Set "GUID=%%~nxa")
If Not Defined GUID (Echo=Unable to find Office Product&GoTo :EndIt)
If %GUID:~20,1% Equ 1 Set "MOB=64"
If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 4 (Set IOV=10) Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 2 (Set IOV=07) Else (
      If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 5 (Set IOV=13) Else (Set IOV=??)))
Echo=&Echo= Office 20%IOV% %MOB%-bit Product installed on a %MWB%-bit OS
:EndIt
```

I would like to customize this script to to make some other stuff if the output is like this

> Office 20?? 32-bit Product installed on a 64-bit OS

```
If Echo= Office 2007 32-bit Product installed on a 64-bit OS (run another script or command)
```

Can somebody help me implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution my self:

```
IF %MOB%==32 IF %MWB%==64 (Echo commands)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't make sense.  It should explain where to place that code or show the entire corrected script.

Answer (score 0):

The original question and accepted answer here didn't make sense to me but this is the only place I could find a batch script that would reveal the Office bitness.  Unfortunately this code was a bit dated and didn't work with the Office 2016/365 that I was using.  I found another registry location that works for me and updated the script as follows.

```vb
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal
COLOR 71
TITLE %~n0
CLS
ECHO Detecting Office Bitness...

Set "IOV=" & Set "MWB=32" & Set "MOB="

REM --- Determine the Windows bitness
ECHO=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%|Find "64">Nul&&(Set "KEY=\Wow6432Node"&Set "MWB=64")

REM --- Determine the Office bitness
REM This registry location may be more geared to O365.  BS 7/19/2022
for /f "tokens=3 delims=, " %%B in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v Platform') do set "MOB=%%B"

REM --- Determine the Office version number
for /f "tokens=3 delims=, " %%B in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport') do set "IOV=%%B"

ECHO.
ECHO Office %IOV% %MOB% product installed on a %MWB%-bit OS
ECHO.

Pause
```

**Output**

> Detecting Office Bitness...
>
> Office 16.0.14931.20604 x86 product installed on a 64-bit OS
>
> Press any key to continue . . .