# Script to check office bit version and install exe based on that

Tags: batch-file, ms-office

I want to write a script that will check the office bit version and if 64 bit version, run this exe, else run this other exe. I can;t seem to find a script that would do that. I see OS version checking, but we have 64 bit OS with 32 bit office, so I need to check the bit version of office. Prefer to make this a .bat file if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Been done a dozen times already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820375/batch-file-check-office-architecture-version

Comment: This just tells me if it is 32 or 64 bit, I am looking for the script to look and then execute based on what it finds. Not just output it to me for viewing.