# Batch File to Copy based on Office Version

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ms-office

I'd like to create a batch file that will check the user environment for the type of MSOffice installation (32-bit or 64-bit) then copy the file specific to that environment. I started with this code, to get the version

```
     Echo off&SetLocal
Set "KEY="&Set "GUID="&Set "IOV="&Set "MWB=32"&Set "MOB=32"
Echo=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%|Find "64">Nul&&(
   Set "KEY=\Wow6432Node"&Set "MWB=64")
Set "KEY=HKLM\Software%KEY%\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
For /f "Delims=" %%a In ('Reg Query %KEY% /k /f "*-001B-*0FF1CE}"') Do (
   If Not Defined GUID Set "GUID=%%~nxa")
If Not Defined GUID (Echo=Unable to find Office Product&GoTo :EndIt)
If %GUID:~20,1% Equ 1 Set "MOB=64"
If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 4 (Set IOV=10) Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 2 (Set IOV=07) Else (
      If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 5 (Set IOV=13) Else (Set IOV=??)))
Echo=&Echo= Office 20%IOV% %MOB%-bit Product installed on a %MWB%-bit OS
```

from [Batch file check office architecture version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820375/batch-file-check-office-architecture-version) but would like to expand it a bit more to be ably to copy.
I'm trying

```
If "MOB=32" copy /y "\\file(32-Bit).exe" c:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
    Else copy /y "\\file(64-Bit).exe" c:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
Echo=&Echo= Copy Completed! Have A Nice Day!
```

but keep getting "copy not expected at this time", also tried using xcopy and got the same result. This would really help with deployment in a mixed environment, any ideas? pretty sure the syntax is wrong =(

Comment: `If "MOB=32"` should be `If %MOB%==32`

Comment: Read the Help for the `IF ` command.  It will show you the exact syntax for using and `IF ... ELSE` command.

Comment: I recognise that [code](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5383#p33104). Glad it was found useful!

Comment: @Compo thanks for the code! but it doesn't seem to be working on 64-bit installs. Also, how could I tweak this so instead of looking for the MS Word version it looks for the Ms Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If %MOB%==32 (copy /y "\\file(32-Bit).exe" c:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
 ) Else (copy /y "\\file(64-Bit).exe" c:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop)
```

1. There must be a separator before the opening parenthesis of the `IF` true-condition target
2. That opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`
3. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a separator and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line
4. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line

ie

```
if condition (
 something
) else (
 someotherthing
)
```

Comment: Ok @Magoo after some testing I've realized it works where the Office install is 32-Bit but it doesn't work on a 64-Bit install or rather it still copies the 32-bit file.

Comment: In that case, it would seem that `mob` is being set to 32, not 64. Since `mob` is established as "32" at the start of your routine, and the only place that it can be changed to "64" is if `%GUID:~20,1% Equ 1` then it would appear that the `GUID` you are extracting and expecting to indicate 64-bit does not have the 21st character=1. Note 21st - counting starts from "character 0" for batch substringing. You'd need to check that *that* test is valid given the values returned on the system(s) giving the problem.