# batch file code to detect 32-bit vs 64-bit office not working

Tags: batch-file, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to put together a batch file that would select the appropriate bit version of executables when run by the user. I found this code on stackoverflow:
[Batch file check office architecture version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820375/batch-file-check-office-architecture-version)
The problem is that it does not work when I paste it into a text file on my desktop and rename it .bat in my virtual machine that has 64-bit Office 2010 installed: it claims it is 32-bit, the default value set in the code. Not being adept in checking registry entries, I'm wondering if there isn't a ready-made version out there somewhere that actually works. I'm also wondering why there isn't a simple way to determine this. I would have thought that this is something that Microsoft would make easily accessible to developers.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What difference does it make. Typing `winword` will always start it.

Comment: And developers usually have no need to know. My 32 bit scripts will work fine on either version of Word and vice versa.

Comment: [How-to: Detecting 64 bit vs 32 bit](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-64bit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to check the bitness, version and install location of Microsoft Office, you could give this script a test to see if it works for you any better:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Start "" /D "%__CD__%" "%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe" /C "%~f0"&Exit /B)
Set /A "OSA=MWB=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"
If %OSA%==86 Set "MWB=32"
Set "MOB="&Set "GUID="&Set "REG=%__AppDir__%reg.exe"
Call :Chk
If Not Defined MOB If %MWB%==64 Call :Chk \Wow6432Node
If Not Defined MOB (Echo Microsoft Office product not installed&GoTo :EndIt
)Else If Not Defined IOV (Echo Unable to determine Microsoft Office version
    GoTo :EndIt)
Echo %MWB%-bit OS with an Office 20%IOV% %MOB%-bit product installed in %OIL%
:EndIt
>Nul Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

:Chk
Set "MOB="&Set "GUID="&Set "OIL="
Set "Key=HKLM\Software%1\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
For /F Delims^= %%A In ('""%REG%" Query "%Key%" /K /F "*-001B-*0FF1CE}""'
)Do Set "GUID=%%~nxA"&GoTo :Next
:Next
If Not "%GUID:~-1%"=="}" Set "GUID="
If Not Defined GUID Exit /B
Set "MOB=32"&If "%GUID:~20,1%"=="1" Set "MOB=64"
If "%GUID:~4,1%"=="2" Set "IOV=07"
If "%GUID:~4,1%"=="4" Set "IOV=10"
If "%GUID:~4,1%"=="5" Set "IOV=13"
If "%GUID:~4,1%"=="6" Set "IOV=16"
If Not Defined IOV Exit /B
For /F Tokens^=2* %%A In ('""%REG%" Query "%Key%\%GUID%" /V "InstallLocation""'
)Do Set "OIL=%%B"
Exit /B
```

Please note however, that this script was designed to work with Windows Microsoft Office products from versions `2007` up to `2016` inclusive. The script only checks for a specific uninstall key for Microsoft Word, *(it is assumed that only in very rare cases would somebody install Office without including the Word product)*, and there is no guarantee that all versions will use the same uninstall key.

*I will not be modifying this code for any additions/changes to your question, or providing help on modifications for purposes other than those for which it was intended.*

Comment: Compo's code does work for me. Thanks. I have however found a way to accomplish what I want to do, without using the batch file, so I guess I don't "need" it. But it is good to know. Not sure why I'm accumulating negative votes. Poor first experience for a newbie.

Comment: So that's what that greyed-out check mark is for!