# FOR tokens batch command can't hide error "ERROR: The system was unable to find..."

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm doing a simple script to check MS Office version reading registry key value. Will be scenarios where the key won't exist (not office installed) I used many times reg.exe query KEY/Check 2>nul but can't make that work inside a FOR line. 
This is the line:

```
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /C:"(Default)"') do set _Off_ver=%%a
```

I tried:

```
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer" 2>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /C:"(Default)"') do set _Off_ver=%%a
```

or

```
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /C:"(Default)"'2>nul ) do set _Off_ver=%%a
```

and in many other places but I end up with the error:

```
> was unexpected at this time.
```

Anyone know how I can hide the error:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Inside that FOR Line?

THANKS

Comment: `2^>nul` ........

Comment: @jeb thanks! I just found the same, Still not sure why they use of ^ inside the FOR, but will read about it :)

Comment: I have no idea from your question whether you are trying to determine the version from a Click-to-Run or MSI installed Office product. If it's a pre-2019 MSI version, please feel free to take a look at [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700544) which, can do so, _(in that case, using the Word product)_. If you have any questions specific to that answer, feel free to comment appropriately under that answer.

Comment: Unable to hide, but also unable to catch...

Answer (score 0):

At the same time as Jeb replied I found a post (not related to this actually) that used 2^>nul. I'm not sure why the ^, but it worked.

The final line is:

```
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer" 2^> nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /C:"(Default)"') do set _Off_ver=%%a
```

THANKS!

Comment: The reason is: The command inside the FOR is parsed by the batch parser, when there is an unescaped character like `>` or `|` it would be used on the `FOR` command itself, not on your `reg.exe` command, and that always fails.

Comment: same as for `^|`, which you did without questioning.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I really appreciate it! :)